# FOSUserBundle redirect after Authentication Fails | redirect after logout

Tags: fosuserbundle

im using FOSUserBundle for Symfony2. How can i change the page redirection after a authentication failed and after a logout?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can customize your form login in security.yml :

Example:

```
  firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                failure_path: /login_failure_redirect
            logout:
                target: /logout_redirect
```